# Remove multiple quotes in json encoded array

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress

is it possible to strip double quotes from json encoded array?
Exaample:

```
{"96":{"term_id":96,"name":"AS Roma","slug":"as-roma","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":100,"taxonomy":"klient","description":"HWDP","parent":0,"count":5,"object_id":1800,"filter":"raw"},"100":{"term_id":100,"name":"Atletico Madrid","slug":"atletico-madrid","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":104,"taxonomy":"klient","description":""vamos amigos"","parent":0,"count":6,"object_id":1800,"filter":"raw"}}
```

This is an array of values from wordpress get_the_terms function. As you may see one of those values "description":""vamos amigos"" has doubled double quotes (the input text in description is inside quotes). Which gives me an error on ajax response. I've tried everything to strip this double quotes - nothing works for me? 
I would appreciate any indications.

Comment: How you tried str_replace on the double quotes? str_replace( '"', '""', $json )

Comment: @casi your json is not valid, I'm receiving errors over it, correct those to proceed. Validate using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: the question is where is this string coming from? what piece of code outputs that?

Comment: @Tjoene str_replace doesnt work in this case

Comment: @cs1193 sure it's not valid - the problem is in ""vamos amigos"" doubled quotes - my question was how to strip those quotes

Comment: Using `str_replace('""', '"', $json)` [works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77bd8c7e34344725d3e1995feb7677f0238c8c6e). @Tjoene has his arguments backwards.

Comment: @cpilko Nice catch, didn't see it.